# IBMCloud Kubernetes doesn't pull images from DockerHub

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, docker-registry

I've created a new Kubernetes cluster in IBMCloud. All new Pods that use public DockerHub images fail with "failed to resolve reference", "failed to do request: Head" and "i/o timeout" errors. Trying to pull public images. I never experienced this with EKS, GKE, OpenShift, or other clusters. Not sure why it couldn't pull the images from DockerHub. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60570621/21404450

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does the trick. My cluster was in VPC. Adding an Public Gateway and Attaching it in every subnet makes it work.